# Generate and render HTML from a set of inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a word matching exercise that takes a set of inputs. The program reads the HTML from the input boxes. Then the html is displayed in a textarea element.

When the user clicks "render html" the key words and descriptions are displayed. The HTML displayed by the program are the values are taken from value of the textarea element.

The input elements for the html are:

```
                 <div id="inputBoxes" class="inputBoxes">
                    <title>Input:</title>
                    <div class="row">
                      Title: <input id= "title_input" type="text">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row">
                      Key Term 1: <input id="el1" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      Description 1: <input id="dl1" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      Key Term 2: <input id="el2" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      Description 2: <input id="dl2" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have 3 global variables to keep track of the numberOfInputs, htmlGenerated, htmlRendered. The reasoning behind this is to check if

1. New inputs have been added. If new inputs have been added then when the user clicks generate HTML those new inputs should be added. When the user clicks render HTML those new inputs should be added.
2. Check if html has been generated. If the HTML was generated then it should be removed before generating new HTML.
3. Check if html has been rendered. If the HTML was rendered then it should be removed before rendering new HTML.

The global variables used are

```
    // initially html is not generated.
    var htmlGenerated = false;
    // number of inputs start out as 2.
    var numberOfInputs = 2;
    // initially no addtional inputs have been added.
    var addMore = false;
    // initially html is not rendered
    var htmlRendered = false;
```

I've created three methods for accomplishing this goal.

1. `generate_html()`
2. `add_more()`
3. `render_html()`

There is a reset function that should remove the controls, the textarea, and the rendered html.

```
function generate_html() {

      //have we added more?
      if(addMore && htmlGenerated){
        // then delete the old textarea.
        textarea = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
        textarea.remove();
        // delete the controls.
        controls = document.getElementById("program1");
        controls.remove();
      }

    
      //has the html already been generated? 
      if(!htmlGenerated){
        const e_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='el']");
        const d_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='dl']");
        const title = document.getElementById('title_input').value;
        let elArray = [];
        let dlArray = [];
        e_inputs.forEach( i => { if(i.value) elArray.push(i.value) });
        d_inputs.forEach( i => { if(i.value) dlArray.push(i.value) });

        let text = title + "\n";
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length; i++) {
            text += `${elArray[i]}:${dlArray[i]}\n`;
        }

        //fetch the results box
        results = document.getElementById("results");

        //create textarea
        textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.setAttribute("id","generated_html_textarea");
        
        // initialize blank html
        html = '';

        //create key inputs
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
          html += '<div id="s';
          id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
          html += id;
          html +='\" class=\"draggyBox-small\">';
          html += elArray[i-numberOfInputs];
          html +='</div>\n';
        }
  
        //create description inputs
        html += '<table id=\"tablestyle\">'
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
          html += '<td id="row';
          id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
          html += id;
          html +='">\n';
          html += '\t\t<div id=\"t';
          html +=i-numberOfInputs;
          html +='" class=\"ltarget\"></div>\n \t</td >\n \t<td  id=\"d2\">'
          html +=dlArray[i-numberOfInputs];
          html +='</td >\n </tr>\n';
        }
        html += '</table>';

        // html generation is done.
        htmlGenerated = true;
        textarea.value = html;
        results.appendChild(textarea);

        // Generate reset, show answer, , and render html buttons
        controls = document.createElement("div");
        controls.setAttribute("id","program1");
        controls.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
        controls.innerHTML +=  '<span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="one()">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset()">Reset</button><button id = "renderHTMLButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="render_html()">Render html</button> <span id = "audio" style=""> <a href="" title="Turns Text-to-Speech Output On or Off" class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none;"><img id="bg" src="audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;"/> </a> </span> </span>';
        results.appendChild(controls);
      }
    }
```

```
function add_more() {
      // we've added more inputs.
      addMore = true;

      // set html generated to false, because new inputs have been added.
      htmlGenerated = false;
      
      // increment the number of inputs.
      numberOfInputs++;

      //fetch the input boxes.
      inputs = document.getElementById("inputBoxes");
      
      //create a new row for a key term.
      row = document.createElement("div");
      row.setAttribute("class","row");

      // set the key term text.
      row.innerHTML = "Key Term ";
      row.innerHTML +=numberOfInputs;
      row.innerHTML +=" :";

      // create the input for the key.
      key = document.createElement("input");
      key.setAttribute("id","el"+numberOfInputs);

      //add the key to the row.
      row.appendChild(key);

      //create a row for the new description.
      row2 = document.createElement("div");
      row2.setAttribute("class","row");

      // set the description text.
      row2.innerHTML = "Description  "
      row2.innerHTML+=numberOfInputs;
      row2.innerHTML+=" :";

      // create the description input
      description = document.createElement("input");
      description.setAttribute("id","dl"+numberOfInputs);

      // add the description to the row.
      row2.appendChild(description);

      // add the rows for the key and the description to the inputBoxes.
      inputs.appendChild(row);
      inputs.appendChild(row2);
    }
```

```
function render_html(){
      // was html rendered?
      if(!htmlRendered){
        textarea  = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
        generated_html = textarea.value;
        console.log(generated_html);
        maincontentstyle = document.getElementById("maincontentstyle");
        rendered_html = document.createElement("div");
        rendered_html.setAttribute("id","rendered_html");
        rendered_html.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
        rendered_html.innerHTML +=  generated_html;
        maincontentstyle.appendChild(rendered_html);
        htmlRendered = true;
      }
    }
```

```
function reset() {
      // reset the htmGenerated to false.
      htmlGenerated = false;
      htmlRendered  = false;
      numberOfInputs = 2;
      var someVarName = true;
      sessionStorage.setItem("someVarKey1", someVarName);
      window.location.reload();
    }
```

The issue that I'm facing is:

When the user clicks generate HTML with the initial inputs set to valid values the generated HTML is created properly. When the user clicks add more and then clicks generated html a second div with a second textarea and second set of controls are created. This should not happen. The original textarea and controls should be replaced.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `add_more()`, comment out the `htmlGenerated = false;` line (since clicking the "add more" button doesn't remove the generated html) and in `generate_html()` add `htmlGenerated = false;` after `controls.remove();`.

```js
// initially html is not generated.
var htmlGenerated = false;
// number of inputs start out as 2.
var numberOfInputs = 2;
// initially no addtional inputs have been added.
var addMore = false;
// initially html is not rendered
var htmlRendered = false;

function generate_html() {
  //have we added more?
  if (addMore && htmlGenerated) {
    // then delete the old textarea.
    textarea = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
    textarea.remove();
    // delete the controls.
    controls = document.getElementById("program1");
    controls.remove();
    
    
    
    htmlGenerated = false;
    
    
    
  }


  //has the html already been generated? 
  if (!htmlGenerated) {
    const e_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='el']");
    const d_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='dl']");
    const title = document.getElementById('title_input').value;
    let elArray = [];
    let dlArray = [];
    e_inputs.forEach(i => {
      if (i.value) elArray.push(i.value)
        });
    d_inputs.forEach(i => {
      if (i.value) dlArray.push(i.value)
        });

    let text = title + "\n";
    for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length; i++) {
      text += `${elArray[i]}:${dlArray[i]}\n`;
    }

    //fetch the results box
    results = document.getElementById("results");

    //create textarea
    textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.setAttribute("id", "generated_html_textarea");

    // initialize blank html
    html = '';

    //create key inputs
    for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length + numberOfInputs; i++) {
      html += '<div id="s';
      id = (1 + i - numberOfInputs);
      html += id;
      html += '\" class=\"draggyBox-small\">';
      html += elArray[i - numberOfInputs];
      html += '</div>\n';
    }

    //create description inputs
    html += '<table id=\"tablestyle\">'
    for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length + numberOfInputs; i++) {
      html += '<td id="row';
      id = (1 + i - numberOfInputs);
      html += id;
      html += '">\n';
      html += '\t\t<div id=\"t';
      html += i - numberOfInputs;
      html += '" class=\"ltarget\"></div>\n \t</td >\n \t<td  id=\"d2\">'
      html += dlArray[i - numberOfInputs];
      html += '</td >\n </tr>\n';
    }
    html += '</table>';

    // html generation is done.
    htmlGenerated = true;
    textarea.value = html;
    results.appendChild(textarea);

    // Generate reset, show answer, , and render html buttons
    controls = document.createElement("div");
    controls.setAttribute("id", "program1");
    controls.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
    controls.innerHTML += '<span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="one()">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset()">Reset</button><button id = "renderHTMLButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="render_html()">Render html</button> <span id = "audio" style=""> <a href="" title="Turns Text-to-Speech Output On or Off" class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none;"><img id="bg" src="audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;"/> </a> </span> </span>';
    results.appendChild(controls);
  }
}

function add_more() {
  // we've added more inputs.
  addMore = true;

  
  
  
  // set html generated to false, because new inputs have been added.
  // htmlGenerated = false;

  
  
  
  // increment the number of inputs.
  numberOfInputs++;

  //fetch the input boxes.
  inputs = document.getElementById("inputBoxes");

  //create a new row for a key term.
  row = document.createElement("div");
  row.setAttribute("class", "row");

  // set the key term text.
  row.innerHTML = "Key Term ";
  row.innerHTML += numberOfInputs;
  row.innerHTML += " :";

  // create the input for the key.
  key = document.createElement("input");
  key.setAttribute("id", "el" + numberOfInputs);

  //add the key to the row.
  row.appendChild(key);

  //create a row for the new description.
  row2 = document.createElement("div");
  row2.setAttribute("class", "row");

  // set the description text.
  row2.innerHTML = "Description  "
  row2.innerHTML += numberOfInputs;
  row2.innerHTML += " :";

  // create the description input
  description = document.createElement("input");
  description.setAttribute("id", "dl" + numberOfInputs);

  // add the description to the row.
  row2.appendChild(description);

  // add the rows for the key and the description to the inputBoxes.
  inputs.appendChild(row);
  inputs.appendChild(row2);
}

function render_html() {
  // was html rendered?
  if (!htmlRendered) {
    textarea = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
    generated_html = textarea.value;
    console.log(generated_html);
    maincontentstyle = document.getElementById("maincontentstyle");
    rendered_html = document.createElement("div");
    rendered_html.setAttribute("id", "rendered_html");
    rendered_html.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
    rendered_html.innerHTML += generated_html;
    maincontentstyle.appendChild(rendered_html);
    htmlRendered = true;
  }
}

function reset() {
  // reset the htmGenerated to false.
  htmlGenerated = false;
  htmlRendered = false;
  numberOfInputs = 2;
  var someVarName = true;
  sessionStorage.setItem("someVarKey1", someVarName);
  window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
<div id="inputBoxes" class="inputBoxes">
      <title>Input:</title>
      <div class="row">
        Title: <input id= "title_input" type="text" value="t">
      </div>  
      <div class="row">
        Key Term 1: <input id="el1" type="text" value="k1">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        Description 1: <input id="dl1" type="text" value="d1">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        Key Term 2: <input id="el2" type="text" value="k2">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        Description 2: <input id="dl2" type="text" value="d2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onClick="generate_html()">Generate</button>
      <button onClick="add_more()">More</button>
    </div>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <div id="maincontentstyle"></div>
```